# spoj SEQ - Recursive Sequence runtime error

Tags: c++, recursion, c++14

im trying to solve spoj problem SEQ - Recursive Sequence , https://www.spoj.com/problems/SEQ/
i compile and get right answer using g++ in terminal, but when i submit it , it produce runtime error (SIGSEGV) , why this happen? i really want to know the cause of error
and i want to know why i need to do mod also inside the matrix?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#define rep(i,n) for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
using namespace std;

typedef long long int ll;
typedef vector<vector<ll> > matrix;
const ll mod = 1000000000;

matrix mul(matrix A,matrix B,int k){
matrix c(k+1,vector<ll>(k+1));
for(int i=1;i<=k;i++){
  for(int j=1;j<=k;j++){
       for(int l=1;l<=k;l++){
         c[i][j]=(c[i][j]+(A[i][l]*B[l][j]))%mod; 
       }
  }
}
return c;

}

matrix pow(matrix A,int p,int k){
if(p==1)
return A;
if(p%2){
  return mul(A,pow(A,p-1,k),k);

}
matrix X=pow(A, p/2,k); 
return mul(X,X,k); 

}


int fib(int N,vector<ll>b1,vector<ll>c1,int k){
vector<ll>bb(k+1);

rep(i,k){
  bb[i]=b1[i];
}

matrix T(k+1,vector<ll>(k+1));

for(int y=1;y<=k;y++){
  for(int u=1;u<=k;u++){
    if(y+1==u)
    T[y][u]=1;

  }
}

rep(i,k){
  int y=c1.back();
  c1.pop_back();
  T[k][i]=y;
}

if(N<k){
cout<<b1[N]<<endl;
return 0;


}

T=pow(T,N-1,k);

ll res=0;
for(int i=1;i<=k;i++)
res=(res+T[1][i]*bb[i])%mod;
cout<<res<<endl;

}

int main(){
  int cas,k,b,c,n;
  cin>>cas;


  rep(i,cas)
   {   

     cin>>k;
       vector<ll>b1(k+1);
   vector<ll>c2(k+1);


    rep(j,k){

      cin>>b;
      b1[j]=b;

    }
     rep(o,k){


        cin>>c;
        c2[o]=c;
      }
      cin>>n;

      fib(n,b1,c2,k);

   }


}
```

this is when i debug it produce output, but it it is written "runtime error "., why is that?
https://ideone.com/J3Yr7c
free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Comment: `#define rep(i,n) for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)` - Ohh $deity, Please don't... And what is this monstrosity `c[i][j]=(c[i][j]+(A[i][l]*B[l][j]))%mod;`? Please don't *ever* write code like that. That's just awful.

Comment: im sorry, this part   c[i][j]=(c[i][j]+(A[i][l]*B[l][j]))%mod;  for is for matrix multiplication  matrix c=matrix A*matrix B

Comment: There are ways to make it *much more* readable. Look into *functions*, *operator overloads*, etc. If you *ever* again find yourself writing a character vomit like that, please think "there's got to be a better way" and go find it...

Comment: @JesperJuhl ok thankyou for advice, this is when i debug online , https://ideone.com/J3Yr7c ,it produce result but it give runtime error ..

Comment: @devss Arrays and vectors start from index 0, not index 1.  If I had a dollar for every time someone tried to write fake 1-based arrays in C++ and winds up with off-by-one errors, I would be a rich man.

Comment: I realize that most colleges are teaching students to 'using namespace std' but in practice that's a horrible idea. By doing so, you immediate pollute the global namespace with EVERY STL type that exists in your included header files. There isn't much effort in typing std::vector<T>

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thankyou is that the cause? but i make the array in first collumn all zero, and all index start from 1 to k, and i initialize the array to k+1 to make sure it can handle 0 to k+1

Comment: @devss -- Do not do that.  Start at 0.  And your code still has the horrible `rep` macro.

Comment: @devss Your `fib` function does not return a value on all code paths.  Are you reading your compiler warnings?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thankyou but how you know the error is because fib function not return value? in my copiler it produce output with no warning, but in ideone it gave error output, but i modified the code to return int , https://ideone.com/vaVWBo seems the error is gone(?)

Comment: *how you know the error is because fib function not return value?* -- It doesn't matter if that's the cause of the error. Returning nothing from a function that is supposed to return a value is *undefined behavior*.  If at the very last line in `fib` you do this `std::cout << "Oops\n";` do you see `Oops` displayed?  If you do, then your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ok thankyou so much!! , but  still it produce wrong answer, maybe it still have some problem with the logic  , but thanks for the help!!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i manage to get accepted, after dealing with some edge case thanks for the help!!!